# Problems with mdframed

Tags: spacing, mdframed, matlab

I am trying to put a box around matlab code but the bottom of the box sits extremely close to the next line. I try a line break but it does not work. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
...get,\\

\begin{mdframed}
\begin{verbatim}
S = 55; % Value of the underlying
...
V =
    2.2147   %This is the value of our put option
\end{verbatim}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
bla bla bla
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\usepackage` doesn't work inside the document.

Comment: Try passing the options `skipabove=\topsep,skipbelow=\topsep` (for instance) to your `mdframed` environment.

Comment: Sorry Jubobs I do not understand what you mean passing the options.

Comment: Consider using the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891) of mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add vertical space above and below an `mdframed` environment by assigning nonzero (length) values to the `skipabove` and `skipbelow` optional keys, respectively. For instance:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

favorite
I am trying to put a box around matlab code but the bottom of the box sits extremely close
to the next line. I try a line break but it does not work. Any ideas?

...get,\\

\begin{mdframed}[skipabove=\topsep,skipbelow=\topsep]
\begin{verbatim}
S = 55; % Value of the underlying
...
V =
    2.2147   %This is the value of our put option
\end{verbatim}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: If you use the current version at github it works out of the box.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel "Out of the box"; is that a pun? I'm not sure I see what you mean...

Comment: I added `\topsep` as default option for `skipabove`

Answer (score 3):

<sub>This is to show an alternative for matlab code with highlighting.</sub>

It is better to use [mcode](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=http://web.mit.edu/~paul_s/www/14.170/matlab/mcode.sty&ei=9nd-UbrYFs_PrQeOkIG4DA&usg=AFQjCNEREqKiayfv6YFeDcw1JZReuYUypg&sig2=_HMhFMzqY_3JYBYfN_zqZA&bvm=bv.45645796,d.bmk) to typeset the matlab codes. `mcode` internally uses `listings` package and offers features like different colored text etc.

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}

% load package with ``framed'' and ``numbered'' option.
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\lstset{
    rulecolor=\color{black}
}

% something NOT relevant to the usage of the package.
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{18pt}

\begin{document}
 The following demo block shows some matlab code:
\begin{lstlisting}
for i = 1:3
    if i >= 5                    % literate programming replacement some thing to fill in the space
        disp('cool');           % comment with some §\mcommentfont\LaTeX\ in it: $\mcommentfont\pi x^2$§
    end
    really really long really really long really really long really really long really really long line % blaaaaaaaa
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

You can add captions by using

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=My code here]
```

Comment: Check out the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; it's aimed at highlighting Matlab code in a more "pedantic" way than `mcode` does `:)`