# Adding a caption or title to a listing in an mdframed environment

Tags: sectioning, listings

I have several pieces of Matlab script I have put into boxes using the below method. I want to be able to call them listings 1 2 3 4 etc. Preferably a command that will do it automatically for me. New to LaTeX so no idea I have searched and found very little.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{mdframed}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{mdframed}[skipabove=\topsep,skipbelow=\topsep]
    \begin{verbatim}
    S = 55; % Value of the underlying
   ...
    V =
        2.2147   %This is the value of our put option
    \end{verbatim}
    \end{mdframed}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `mcode` or `listings` packages instead of using `mdframed` and `verbatim`, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53238/putting-in-matlab-codes-in-a-box-as-figures

Comment: I am aware of mcode. I have a lot of these and was hoping to find a way to just assign them names. Do you know if it is at least possible to do this?

Comment: See my answer to your question here: [Problems with mdframed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111323)

Comment: @KaneBlackburn I updated my answer with a new possibility that might interest you.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to keep your current settings (`mdframed`+`verbatim`), you can use the `\captionof` command from the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package to obtain a caption. Another option is to use the features provided by the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package (instead of using `mdframed`+`verbatim`) to write your listings; the `lstlisting` environment gives you the possibility to have a frame and caption for your listings:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{labelsep=none}

\lstset{frame={tblr}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={\null}]
    S = 55; % Value of the underlying
   ...
    V =
        2.2147   %This is the value of our put option
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{mdframed}[skipabove=\topsep,skipbelow=\topsep]
\captionof{lstlisting}{}
\begin{verbatim}
    S = 55; % Value of the underlying
   ...
    V =
        2.2147   %This is the value of our put option
\end{verbatim}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want this to apply automatically, you can surround `verbatim` with a `mdframed` and use the `settings` key to automatically generate the caption:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[lstlisting]{labelsep=none}

\surroundwithmdframed[
  skipabove=\topsep,
  skipbelow=\topsep,
  settings=\captionof{lstlisting}{}
]{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
    S = 55; % Value of the underlying
   ...
    V =
        2.2147   %This is the value of our put option
\end{verbatim}

\begin{verbatim}
    S = 55; % Value of the underlying
   ...
    V =
        8.2147   %This is the value of our put option
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. I was deliberating over having the font how I wanted but the title not or the other way around. Just what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the `listings` package, with which you can both enter code snippets and load complete (or partial) files into your output. Referencing single listings is fairly easy too.

I tried to make you a small example, and hope this helps.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Matlab,
    frame=single,
    caption=Some Matlab code,
    label=matlab]
        S = 55; % Value of the underlying
        ...
        V = 2.2147   %This is the value of our put option
\end{lstlisting}

Here is some more text, which is then also referring to listing~\ref{matlab}, which we will explain later. There is also a second example, which is shown in listing~\ref{python}.

\lipsum[1]

\lstinputlisting[lastline=25,
    language=Python,
    frame=single,
    caption=Python code,
    label=python]
    {/path/to/python/file.py}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```